# Django constance - on save method

Tags: django

Is there any way to call django command after changing constance value? I need to call:

```
python manage.py installtasks
```

for my kronos cron jobs. I don't have any idea how can I set this. In constance docs I found:

```
from constance.signals import config_updated

@receiver(config_updated)
def constance_updated(sender, key, old_value, new_value, **kwargs):
    print(sender, key, old_value, new_value)
```

but I don't know what is receiver (I get "NameError: name 'receiver' is not defined") and where should I put this code. Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could import the decorator,

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
```

Comment: It was so simple...:) Works great. Can you help me with python manage.py installtask command. I thought it would be easy to call it but it is not... What is a proper way to call such command inside django app?